# Не отображается pagination переделываю в pdo с php mysql

Tags: php, pdo

```
Вот полный код
```

Index.php

```
`<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="UA-ru">
<head>
    <?php
        $website_title = "Title";
        require_once "php/head.php";
    ?>
</head>
<body>
    <?php require_once "php/header.php"; ?>
    <main class="container mt-5">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 mb-3">
                <?php
                    include_once ("db.php");
                    $db = new Database;
                    require_once "php/pagination.php";
                    // текущая страница
                    $page = $_GET["page"];
                    if ($page < 1 or $page == "") $page = 1;

                    // количество строк-статей на стр.
                    $limit = 2;

                    // начало выборки из БД
                    $start = getStart($page, $limit);

                    $news = getAllArticles($start, $limit);
                    for ($i = 0; $i < count($news); $i++) 
                    echo 
                    "<h2>" .$news[$i]['title']."</h2>" . 
                    "<p>" .$news[$i]['intro_text']."</p>" .
                    "<p>" . "<b>Автор статьи:</b>" . "<mark>" . $news[$i]['author']. "<mark>" . "</p>" .
                    "<a href='news.php?id=" . $news[$i]['id'] . "' title='" . $news[$i]['title'] . "'>" ."<button class='btn btn-warning mb-5'>Прочитать больше</button>"."</a>" ;
                    echo "<br />" .pagination($page, $limit);

                    // вывод новостей
                    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM `news` ORDER BY `date` DESC';
                    $result = countArticles($sql);
                    echo($result);
                    while($result){
                        echo"
                            <h2>$row->title</h2>
                            <p>$row->intro_text</p>
                            <p><b>Автор статьи:</b> <mark>$row->author</mark></p>
                            <a href='news.php?id=$row->id' title='$row->title'>
                                <button class='btn btn-warning mb-5'>Прочитать больше</button>
                            </a>
                        ";
                    }
                ?>
            </div>

            <?php require_once "php/aside.php"; ?>
        </div>
    </main> 
 <?php require_once "php/footer.php"; ?>
</body>
 </html>`
```

pagination.php

```
`<?php
include_once("db.php");

function getAllArticles($start, $limit) {
    $db = new Database;
    $result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `news` ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT ".$start.", ".$limit);
    return $result;
}

function countArticles() {
    $db = new Database();
    $result = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `news`");
    $row = count($result);
    return $row[0];
}

function getStart($page, $limit) {
    return $limit * ($page - 1);
}

function pagination($page, $limit) {
    // общее кол-во строк в БД
    $count_articles = countArticles();
    // общее количество стр.
    $count_pages = ceil($count_articles / $limit);
    if ($page > $count_pages) $page = $count_pages;
    $prev = $page - 1;
    $next = $page + 1;
    if ($prev < 1) $prev = 1;
    if ($next > $count_pages) $next = $count_pages;
    $pagination = "";
    if ($count_pages > 1) {
        // pagination
        if ($page == 1) {
            $pagination .= "<span>1Первая </span>";
            $pagination .= "<span>1Предыдущая </span>";
        }
        else {
            $pagination .= "<a href='index.php'>2Первая </a>";
            if ($prev == 1) $pagination .= "<a href='index.php'>2Предыдущая </a>";
            else $pagination .= "<a href='index.php?page=".$prev."'>21Предыдущая </a>";
        }
        for ($i = 1; $i <= $count_pages; $i++) {
            if ($i == $page) $pagination .= "<span> ".$i." </span>";
            elseif ($i == 1) $pagination .= "<a href='index.php'> ".$i." </a>";
            else $pagination .= "<a href='index.php?page=".$i."'> ".$i." </a>";
        }
        if ($page == $count_pages) {
            $pagination .= "<span> 3Следующая</span>";
            $pagination .= "<span> 3Последняя</span>";
        }
        else {
            $pagination .= "<a href='index.php?page=".$next."'> 4Следующая</a>";
            $pagination .= "<a href='index.php?page=".$count_pages."'> 4Последняя</a>";
        }
    }
    return $pagination;
   }

 ?>`
```

Ошибка `Notice: Undefined index: page in /home/ecnlua/public_html/sitenew/index.php on line 19`

Comment: зачем в индекс подключение к базе? почитай http://www.php.su/articles/?cat=examples&page=062 для начала должно помочь

Comment: @AlukardNosferatu Подключение убрал! Ошибка именно в строке `$page = $_GET[“page”];`

Comment: Дк потому что вы не передаёте ‘page’ в $_GET. У вас же написана ошибка и фактически ее решение. Давайте будем уважать друг друга :) и прежде чем писать вопрос почему не работает, хотя бы попробовать перевести в гугл переводчике, если английский не знаете. Просто на ваш вопрос мало кто будет отвечать, ибо просто лень писать из-за такой ерунды.

Comment: Вот ваше решение проблемы: `Notice: Undefined index: page in /home/ecnlua/public_html/sitenew/index.php on line 19`. Вам интерпретатор указал где и что не так, и что надо поправить.

Comment: @АлександрСавченко попробуй все переделать по тому примеру что я привел, так как у тебя get передается пустым вот и ругается

Comment: @AlukardNosferatu ошибку исправил, тот пример не придерживает php7. Но страницы все равно не отображаются, ошибок нет

Comment: @AlukardNosferatu исправленный код, но страницы не отображаются
'$page = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 1;'
Ломаю голову уже какой день, но этой мелочи не вижу(

Comment: @АлександрСавченко сколько новостей у тебя в базе? что бы пагинатион сработал обычно нужно от 10 новостей, у меня так на фрамеворке работает

Answer (score 0):

Нужно было проверить была ли установлена переменная значением или нет через **isset**.

---

Заменил `$page = $_GET["page"];` на `$page = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 1;`